# Which knots can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in a centrally symmetric manner?

Tags: symmetry, knot-theory

For which knots $K$ is there an embedding of $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for which $x\in K\iff (-x)\in K$?

Obviously, the unknot can be: take the circle given by $(\sin(t),\cos(t),0)$ for $t\in[0,2\pi)$.

More generally, given a knot $K$ and its mirror image $K'$, the knot sum $K\# K'$ can be embedded in a centrally symmetric manner by placing $K$ far from the origin, placing its negated copy, and bridging the gap between them by two straight lines.

In the negative direction, any chiral knot can't be embedded symmetrically, because the inversion of $\mathbb{R}^3$ reverses chirality but fixes such an embedding. (I think this can be made more precise with notions of amphichirality, but I'm not sure I understand the definitions and consequences well enough to make confident statements here.)

What other things can we prove about such embeddings? At a minimum, does anyone have an example of a centrally symmetric drawing of a nontrivial prime knot?

Comment: Are you including links in your question?  If so, then you can get lots of torus links.  Also, the Borromean rings and things like that.  But if you only want knots, then I am pretty sure they torus knots won't work.

Comment: I'd be a little curious about a classification of links, though they seem easier to find examples of ([Solomon's knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon%27s_knot) clearly works, for instance). In particular, I can't find a way to make the Hopf link work, but I don't know how to prove this is impossible. Would be interested to see a resolution of the Hopf link in either direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any knot with an involution which reverses the orientation on $\mathbb{R}^3$, but preserves the orientation on the knot has an embedding of the type you describe. (Equivalently an involution which reverses the orientation on the meridian but preserves the orientation on the longitude.)

I believe such knots are usually called "strongly positive amphicheiral" in the literature. See for example Figure 1(c) in this paper: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1250127863

For a specific hyperbolic knot I would use Snappy (https://snappy.math.uic.edu）to check if the symmetry group has such an element. For example, $4_1$ has exactly two symmetries which reverse the orientation on $S^3$ but preserve the orientation on $4_1$; however, both of these symmetries have order 4 (not 2) so that $4_1$ is not strongly positive amphicheiral.

You can see these order 4 symmetries in the following diagram as a $2\pi/4$ rotation (in either direction) followed by reflection across an $S^2$ intersecting the diagram in the dotted green circle.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJeSJ.png

Comment: Thanks for the information! Strongly positive amphicheirality is a necessary condition as well as a sufficient one, correct? I gather from that paper that $10_{31}$ is one such knot; are there prime examples with fewer crossings? Is it tractable to list all strongly negative amphicheiral knots on at most $k$ crossings for some small $k$?

Comment: Yes, strongly postive amphicheiral is equivalent to the existence of an emebedding in R^3 which is (set-wise) preserved by the x -> -x involution. I'm not sure whether there are fewer-crossing strongly positive amphicheiral knots, but I think Figure 2 in that paper lists all strongly negative amphicheiral knots through 10 crossings. As far as I'm aware nobody has tabulated them beyond that, but it definitely should be tractable. Let me also mention that 10_31 in the Buskirk paper is 10_118 in Rolfsen notation.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification on notation, I would have missed that. Do you know if these same measures can be extended to links to show that e.g. the Hopf link has no such embedding?

Comment: For hyperbolic links it should be easy to check using the same idea. I'm not sure how to go about it for non-hyperbolic links in general, but I think a 2-component strongly positive amphicheiral link has to have linking number 0 (since the crossings come in pairs of opposite sign), which would rule out the Hopf link.